# PHP how to acces multiple array values

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, get, key-value

Hello guys i have this multiple array but i don't realy know how to access the values can i get all values of the company for example i will build an table with this values as shown bellow: is it possible to
build an nested while loop?

```
    <?php
while (($company_name = current($aCompanys)) !== FALSE ){
echo key($aCompanys).'<br />';
next($aCompanys);
}
?>

[CompanyName1+] => Array (
    [Zen] => Array (
        [article] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Kalender
                [1] => 9.99
                [2] => 2017
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => Notizbuch DINA A4
                [1] => 24.99
                [2] => 2017
                )
            )
        )
    [PlenkS] => Array (
        [article] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Kugelschreiber
                [1] => 19.99
                [2] => 2017
                )
            )
        )
    )
[CompanyName2] => Array (
    [asdasd] => Array (
        [article] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Kugelschreiber
                [1] => 19.99
                [2] => 2017
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: What exactly your expectation is? Result?

Comment: CompannyName:Zen: and the whole article array with content

Comment: _and the whole article array with content_ : How will you print an array, just a plain text?

Comment: yeah for the first it would be enough .. later i will put it in a table: that guy who build this array deserves a spcial place in hell :D

Comment: Have you tried with foreach? You can get key and value with it

Comment: yeah already tryed the problem is i get double values for company so the return is CompanyName1 CompanyName1 instead of CompanyName1 CompanyName2 the same thing for the Zen , im on the point to change my sql and remove the double values by jquery cause this array makes me mad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to print the company names as CompanyName1 : Zen , CompanyName2 : Plenks

Please find below complete code for your array, it works fine and gives the desired output.

```
<?php
$main_array = array("CompanyName"=>array("Zen"=>array("Article"=>array(array('kalendar','9.99','2017'),array('Notizbuch DINA A4','24.99','2017'))),"Plensk"=>array("Article"=>array(array('Kugelschreiber','9.99','2017')))),"CompanyName2"=>array("Zen2"=>array(1,2,3),"Plensk2"=>array(1,2,3)));
var_dump($main_array); 

echo "<br /><br />"; 

foreach ($main_array as $i => $values){ 

foreach ($values as $key => $t){ 

echo $i . ":" . $key . "<br />"; 
} 

} 

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can access them for example:

```
$aCompanys[CompanyName1+][Zen][article][0][2];
```

to get this value: "2017"

Comment: `CompanyName1+`, `zen`, `article` are not constants